# 1 Dll, in our libraries... If called from webservice behaves as expected, if called from winform, uses remoting... HUH?

Tags: c#, assemblies, remoting, .net-remoting

That's Pretty much it.

I took a set of Active Directory classes we'd had in our webservices for years, and seperated & migrated it into our Libraries so I could also use them in a winform app I'm whipping up.

Migration worked fine. Running it via the original webservice, works normally, I can debug into the Classes just fine.

Same exact Dll, in my winform app, when I run it in the debugger, it's being called via remoting, and I can't debug it becuase almost everything on the objects are remote proxies.

What the heck did I do differntely to make it behave like this? None of the other classes behave like this.

Any insight is greatly appreicatied.

Thanks,

Cal-

Comment: Are you sure  it's not just in a separate appdomain?

Comment: Don't know for sure, how would I tell?

Comment: All I know is the objects are impossible to inspect as most everything is a remoting proxy.Tks

Comment: On further research it looks like it's beign called via remoting in both instances. I just happend to be looking at an easier to debug object. Does a context bound object get run in a different appDoamin? the Classes derive from ContextBoundObject. Makes sense that the original author would do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just left everything in the webservice and the Winfomrs app calls the webservice to do all the work.
Not what i wanted but it works.

Cal-